# Multiple Invoice Prefixes?

Tags: invoice

I know civiCRM allows invoice prefixes. This is very helpful in distinguishing civiCRM payments in our merchant account from other software systems (like our ecommerce store).

However, is it possible to have multiple invoice prefixes? We use civiCRM for both our donations/contributions and our event registrations. Is it possible to have a separate invoice prefix for our donations and for our events so that we can distinguish between the two in our merchant account reports? This would be simply for accounting purposes.

The only way around this that I can think of is to host two civiCRMs, one for events and one for contributions; however that would really bog down our server, and I'd rather not do that.

Thanks.

Comment: I would think that it would be possible to add some custom code or a hook to prepend a prefix to the invoice number, depending on the financial type of the contribution.  If you have a consultant or developer with whom you work regularly, you might ask them if this is something with which they could assist.

Comment: To create a hook is not easy see http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16871/how-do-i-generate-a-custom-invoice-id